# AWS Lambda: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to fetch data from S3 (.csv) data and put it into DynamoDB. My intention is to put data directly into DynamoDB through AWS Lambda, whenever S3 receives any file, it should invoke Lambda and put data into DynamoDB.
I created an S3 bucket and create a trigger that invoke Lambda as you can see in the following picture.
[image: S3Trigger]

I am also confused what to write in prefix for sub directories: "AgentMegrics/" or "connect/oblab2/Metrics/AgentMetrics/"
All my CSV files are generated in AgentMetrics which is a subdirectory of  Metrics which is a subdirectory of oblab2 which is a subdirectory of connecting which is a subdirectory of my bucket (new-bucket-for-metrics).

Lambda Function

```
import json 
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentMetrics')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    students = file_content.split("\n")
    print("students :",students)
    
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "Agent" : data[0],
                "StartInterval" : data[1],
                "EndInterval" : data[2],
                "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                "Agent on contact time" : data[4],
                "Nonproductive time" : data[5],
                "Online time" : data[6],
                "Lunch Break time" : data[7],
                "Service level 120 seconds" : data[8],
                "After contact work time" : data[9],
                "Contacts handled" : data[10],
                "Contacts queued" : data[11]
           } )
        except Exception as e:
            print("File Completed")
```

The error I am getting

```
    {
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
  "requestId": "5047dd05-4d17-4e8a-8cb8-cc32002f8e9b",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Lambda Test Event

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "new-bucket-for-metrics",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::new-bucket-for-metrics"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "AgentMetrics-2022-02-23T13:30:00Z.csv",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know where I am exactly doing wrong, and I got frustrated as I have posted this around three to four-time this question. I am not getting any response that has remained helpful.
I would really appreciate that if someone helps me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually trying to process the test event as written? Does it refer to a real bucket and key?

Comment: No, I don't want to process the test event as written, I just want to test it simply.

Comment: I also changed the test event to s3 put event with dummy data, that also leads to an error

Comment: After changing test event to default event "S3 Put" event. Now another error appears:  {
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",

Comment: Please don't change the problem (from your GetObject failure to some new PutObject failure). Fix the original one first. Your test event refers to bucket `new-bucket-for-metrics` and key `AgentMetrics-2022-02-23T13:30:00Z.csv`. Your Lambda function, when invoked, attempts to get that object from S3. That attempt fails with NoSuchKey. Obviously, that means either the object doesn't exist or you have incorrectly indicated the bucket/key in your test event. Fix as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the key in S3 should refer to the entire "folder" structure of the object not just the file name.  So assuming you've shared the full information, your test key should be:

connect/oblab2/Metrics/AgentMetrics/AgentMetrics-2022-02-23T13:30:00Z.csv

Of course you'll need to attach a role to the Lambda that has "GetObject" permissions to to this specific location.

Note:  I put folder in quotes because there aren't actually folders in S3, that's just the way they are represented in the console.  I think of the objects has just having really long names with forward slashes allowed for grouping.  Based on this, your prefix in the S3 Notification can be "connect/oblab2/Metrics/AgentMetrics/" assuming you only want files put one level below that.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a file to the source bucket then it worked without any error.

(Info courtesy of @Jarmod)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).